# FPDF refuses to collaborate through inheritance

Tags: php, fpdf

I have two code examples below. One works, but the second (using `extend` to create a new class wrapper) doesn't.

Note, I've greatly simplified the following examples.

### Approach #1

**page.php:**

```
<?php

include("fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF;
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',11);
$pdf->Output();

?>
```

This works as expected. It creates a blank page.

### Approach #2

But then, using the FPDF by inheritance, I get an error (see below the code blocks).

**myPDF.php:**

```
<?php

require ("fpdf.php");

class myPDF extends FPDF {

    function createMyPage() {
        $this->AddPage();
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',11);
        $this->Output();
    }

}

?>
```

**page.php:**

```
<?php

include("myPDF.php");
$pdf = new myPDF;
$pdf->createMyPage();

?>
```

This second approach produces the following PHP warning and FPDF error:

> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /var/www/fpdftest/fpdf.php on line 526 FPDF error: Undefined font: helvetica

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: I don't believe FPDF is still being supported; however, [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) is it's logical successor (also free). If you can (and I know it's not always possible with legacy code) switch to TCPDF. (EDIT: And, I see there forum has recent responses, so maybe it's not as dead as I thought, but I remember distinctly reading the author suggesting people switch to TCPDF.)

Comment: Also, to attempt to answer your question, you might want to call the `$this->FPDF($orientation,$unit,$size);` constructor: http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto6.htm

Comment: Also, are those literally two different errors, or one? As in, the `Warning` and the `FPDF error`?.

Comment: Thanks Jared, the second one was exactly the required thing to make it work. Both errors where caused by the same thing. I'm also grateful that you pointed out TCPDF. I wasn't aware of it. I'm definately going to give it a try.

Comment: No problem, I added that as an answer, and like I said, FPDF may not inactive (the forums certainly don't suggest it's unsupported at least). I really like TCPDF, but FPDF also has it's uses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create your wrapper class, be sure to call the parent constructor:

```
<?php // Always use the full <?php open tag

require ("fpdf.php");

class myPDF extends FPDF {

    // Or, __construct() if you only care about PHP5
    function myPDF($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $size='A4') {
        // Call parent constructor
        $this->FPDF($orientation,$unit,$size);
        // Initialization
        $this->B = 0;
        $this->I = 0;
        $this->U = 0;
        $this->HREF = '';
    }

    function createMyPage() {
        $this->AddPage();
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',11);
        $this->Output();
    }

}
```

http://fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto6.htm